# Java 8 JPA Repository Stream produce two (or more) results?

Tags: java-8, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, java-stream

I have a Java 8 stream being returned by a Spring Data JPA Repository.  I don't think my usecase is all that unusual, there are two (actually 3 in my case), collections off of the resulting stream that I would like collected.

```
Set<Long> ids = // initialized
try (Stream<SomeDatabaseEntity> someDatabaseEntityStream = 
             someDatabaseEntityRepository.findSomeDatabaseEntitiesStream(ids)) {
    Set<Long> theAlphaComponentIds = someDatabaseEntityStream
            .map(v -> v.getAlphaComponentId())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    // operations on 'theAlphaComponentIds' here
}
```

I need to pull out the 'Beta' objects and do some work on those too.  So I think I had to repeat the code, which seems completely wrong:

```
try (Stream<SomeDatabaseEntity> someDatabaseEntityStream = 
             someDatabaseEntityRepository.findSomeDatabaseEntitiesStream(ids)) {
    Set<BetaComponent> theBetaComponents = someDatabaseEntityStream
            .map(v -> v.getBetaComponent())
            .collect(Collectors.toSet());
    // operations on 'theBetaComponents' here
}
```

These two code blocks occur serially in the processing.  Is there clean way to get both Sets from processing the Stream only once?  Note: I do not want some kludgy solution that makes up a wrapper class for the Alpha's and Beta's as they don't really belong together.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can always refactor code by putting the common parts into a method and turning the uncommon parts into parameters. E.g.

```
public <T> Set<T> getAll(Set<Long> ids, Function<SomeDatabaseEntity, T> f)
{
    try(Stream<SomeDatabaseEntity> someDatabaseEntityStream = 
         someDatabaseEntityRepository.findSomeDatabaseEntitiesStream(ids)) {
        return someDatabaseEntityStream.map(f).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```

usable via

```
Set<Long> theAlphaComponentIds = getAll(ids, v -> v.getAlphaComponentId());
// operations on 'theAlphaComponentIds' here
```

and

```
Set<BetaComponent> theBetaComponents = getAll(ids, v -> v.getBetaComponent());
// operations on 'theBetaComponents' here
```

Note that this pulls the “*operations on … here*” parts out of the `try` block, which is a good thing, as it implies that the associated resources are released earlier. This requires that `BetaComponent` can be processed independently of the `Stream`’s underlying resources (otherwise, you shouldn’t collect it into a `Set` anyway). For the `Long`s, we know for sure that they can be processed independently.

Of course, you could process the result out of the `try` block even without the moving the common code into a method. Whether the original code bears a duplication that requires this refactoring, is debatable. Actually, the operation consists a single statement within a `try` block that looks big only due to the verbose identifiers. Ask yourself, whether you would still deem the refactoring necessary, if the code looked like

```
Set<Long> alphaIDs, ids = // initialized
try(Stream<SomeDatabaseEntity> s = repo.findSomeDatabaseEntitiesStream(ids)) {
    alphaIDs = s.map(v -> v.getAlphaComponentId()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
}
// operations on 'theAlphaComponentIds' here
```

Well, different developers may come to different conclusions…

---

If you want to reduce the number of repository queries, you can simply *store* the result of the query:

```
List<SomeDatabaseEntity> entities;
try(Stream<SomeDatabaseEntity> someDatabaseEntityStream = 
     someDatabaseEntityRepository.findSomeDatabaseEntitiesStream(ids)) {
    entities=someDatabaseEntityStream.collect(Collectors.toList());
}
Set<Long> theAlphaComponentIds = entities.stream()
  .map(v -> v.getAlphaComponentId()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
// operations on 'theAlphaComponentIds' here
Set<BetaComponent> theBetaComponents = entities.stream()
  .map(v -> v.getBetaComponent()).collect(Collectors.toSet());
// operations on 'theBetaComponents' here
```